Couldn’t get equations in html when convert word .docx file to html file in C#
I have .net C# application in which I am extracting data from word file and save it in database particularly. To store word all data as it is I am converting the whole word file firstly in HTML and then checking html paragraph one by one.
At the time of converting from word file to html my equations which are in the word document file was convert into image.
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Select();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;

string result = Path.GetTempPath();

string tmpFileName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.FullName;
doc.SaveEncoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUSASCII;
if (File.Exists(result + "temp.html"))
{
    File.Delete(result + "temp.html");
}
doc.SaveAs(result + "temp.html", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);

doc.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument mangledHTML = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
mangledHTML.Load(result + "temp.html");


if (File.Exists(result + "newtemp.html"))
{
    File.Delete(result + "newtemp.html");
}

mangledHTML.Save(result + "newtemp.html");
// Remove standalone CRLF

string badHTML = File.ReadAllText(result + "newtemp.html");
badHTML = badHTML.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "ackThbbtt ");
badHTML = badHTML.Replace("\r\n", " ");
badHTML = badHTML.Replace("ackThbbtt ", "\r\n");
badHTML = badHTML.Replace('�', ' ');
if (File.Exists(result + "finaltemp.html"))
{
    File.Delete(result + "finaltemp.html");
}
File.WriteAllText(result + "finaltemp.html", badHTML);

// Clean up temp files, show the finished result in Notepad
File.Delete(result + "temp.html");
File.Delete(result + "newtemp.html");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document orignalDoc = new Document();
orignalDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(tmpFileName);



Basically, what I want to do is I want to store all word document paragraph data separately in database and I also want it’s all property like font size, font width, font name and font style. So that I can show it in my application as it is as I written in word document file.
To represent it as it is I need to convert it html format and the by sepreting all paragraphs I can store it in database. But when in my word document has paragraph which have equations then

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Select();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;

string result = Path.GetTempPath();

string tmpFileName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.FullName;
doc.SaveEncoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUSASCII;


This code converts my word documents all equations in Images and as it convert in image I can’t show the equation properly in my application.

So I tried to convert this equations in MATHML form but I couldn’t solve this.


Is there a specific reason you are converting the math equations into images ?
Could you use some library to convert the document into the html or maybe if you could have pandoc installed on the machine where your application runs pandoc can take over the conversion and convert the math equations in MathML or LaTex

I used Microsoft.Office.dll like thi Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUSASCII

I am not familiar with the Microsoft.Office.dll, but my question is the same why are you converting the math equations into the IMG?

I want show  that documnet data as it is in my application. That's why I am converting it into HTML

you say in your question:
This code converts my word documents all equations in Images and as it convert in image I can’t show the equation properly in my application.
So i dont know why you are converting in images

I am not converting it to image but when I am converting this word file to HTML
doc.SaveEncoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUSASCII;
my equation changes to the image.
